# Going over the voting limit cap

Tags: discussion, voting, rate-limiting

I realized that I voted 41 times today (see this picture taken from my profile) while the limit is supposed to be 40. Just by curiosity, is there an explanation to that?

[image]

Comment: IIRC if posts get deleted the votes are "returned" but that counter is not reset. This came up before. I think?

Comment: @quid: You think right.

Comment: @Asaf: thanks for the confirmation and finding the dupe.

Comment: @quid: I had to act fast before you were going to realize this and rob me of the opportunity to use my dupehammer on meta! :D